Unable to start the Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console in Visual Studio 2022
Our team just updated from from an older version of VS 2022 to VS 2022 10.9 (.NET 8 support).
When I create an ASP.NET web app or a Blazor web app, I get the following error message:

Unable to start the Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console. If this
probem continues, repair Visual Studio installation, or enable 'Tools
-> Options -> Debugging -> Automatically close the console when debugging stops'

If my team mate logs into my machine, it works. If I log into his machine, then it doesn't work for me.
I guess it's something in the roaming profile that breaks it, however I can't figure out what it is. I tried every single tip I could possibly find on the internet (like making sure that the env. variables don't exceed 2000 chars, etc) and re-installed + repaired  Visual Studio.
Now I'm out of ideas and close to desperation :)
Does anyone has an idea what I could be or if there's a log file that could lead to finding the issue?

Please try to Navigate to the IDE path and run the reset command. Like  E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /ResetSettings.

@JasonPan did that too, sorry forgot to mention.

Try to Remove all with InstallCleanup.exe, the path should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer, you can search it in your side. I found some blogs mentioned InstallCleanup may reset the related setting in Registry.

Hi gsharp, please wait, could you kindly create a new account for testing first? I mean contact IT and create a test account for you, and I will keep to find how  roaming profile  casue the issue.

It may also be a permission issue. You can also contact the IT team to check the difference in permissions between you and your team mate's account.

After confirming the permission issue, if it still not work, we can try InstallCleanup.exe.

Hi @JasonPan creating an account  in our corporate is almost impossible. I've tried InstallCleanup and unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.

Hi @gsharp, try to call devenv /log to see all activity to the log file and check whether there are related error messages. Besides, do you mean your team mate's account and your account (both sign in to the same vs) behaves differently when create an ASP.NET web app  on your machine? If yes, please go to File > Account Settings... and select the Manage Visual Studio profile link to compare the difference between yours and your team mate's.

hi @DouXu-MSFT. Thanks for the hint. Compared the log with the one of my team mate. nothing suspicous. also the profiles are the same.

hi @Jackdaw did that too and no success , also nothing in the eventviewer. as a next step we will re-stage my machine and do a profile reset. thanks all who tried to help. much appreciated.

Since the problem is specific to your user profile, your profile may have become corrupted. Could you try creating a new user profile in Windows and check if the issue still happens when logged in as a new user? If the problem doesn't happen in the new profile, it confirms that the issue is connected to your original profile. Otherwise, this issue is possibly related to the global and profile-specific applications or extensions.

Try a few things. I hope it will resolve your issue.

Clear VS cache: Go to "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio" and delete the folder related to your version of Visual Studio. This will reset some settings and cache data.
Reset User Settings: Go to "Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings".
Check Permission or Run as administrator: Try to run Visual Studio as administrator.
Inspect Logs: Add a system environment variable: "VSDEBUGTRACE=1". Restart the VS. Find the logs in the Output window or a log file in your temp directory.
Disable third-party extensions.

If the above solutions do not resolve your issue, check the following:

Check Windows event logs: Open Event Viewer by Win+R and enter "eventvwr.msc" and check errors or warnings related to VS or .NET under "Windows Logs -> Application" and "Windows Logs -> System".
Check Visual Studio installer logs: Go to "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Installer" and review the log files.

